# LVM Slow flush of cached dirty blocks

Tags: lvm, cache

I have a system with two 4TB SATA disks and two 1TB NVME disks setup in two mirrors using mdadm.
Ubuntu 20.04 installed with one boot on md0 and the rest (md1) is added to vg0 with a root lv with ext4.
I then added the md2 (the nvme disks) to vg0 and created a meta and cache pool, then added it to the root lv as cache (writeback and smq).  This works fine for me...
The 1TB cachepool has now been filled with dirty blocks, and it seems to be very slow to flush the blocks to the SATA disks...
The chunksize is 1M (system default with such a large cache device).
I have tried to "speed up" the flush somehow by changing the cachepolicy to cleaner, changing the migration_threshold option to 32768, and finally I tried to set the cachemode to writethrough, which just give me a line every few seconds...
Flushing 972103 blocks for cache vg0/root.
Flushing 972103 blocks for cache vg0/root.
...
...
Flushing 972103 blocks for cache vg0/root

But it doesn't really put any effort in, to flush the data...
I have "netdata" installed, and I can see that the SATA nore the NVME disks are doing much reads or writes... so I'm not sure what is keeping up this process?

I'm on Ububtu 20.04 and the LVM2 package is: lvm2/focal,focal,now 2.03.07-1ubuntu1 amd64

Any help is welcome :-)

/Heino

Comment: I have been digging... there seems to be an issue with chunksize larger than 1MiB... when I issue the lvs it states "1.0M" which should be smaller than 1MiB... but as far as I can understand it also have to be a multiple of 32k... which seems counter intuitive, since 1MiB isn't divisible by 32k.  anyway the 1M came about automatically when creating the cache-pool as I didn't specify any chunksize... apparently 1M is chosen when you give it a device with 1TB of space...  sadly I'm now stuck as I cannot flush the dirty blocks, so I'm going to try to re-install the setup with a smaller chunksize